# How do I use global variables to access plugin methods in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, global-variables

My experience with jQuery is limited, hence please feel free to edit the question in case the verbiage is incorrect.

While initiating a plugin I'm assigning it to a variable:

```
var test = $('.fancybox').fancybox({
    padding         : 0,
    margin          : 10,
    closeBtn        : false
});
```

Now, I'm trying to access the instance of the plugin and call it's method as:

```
$(document).on('keyup', function(e) {
    var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);

    if (code == 40) {
        test.cancel();
        return false;
    }
});
```

This throws the error — "test is undefined". This as per my understanding appears to be problem with the scope of the variable `test`. However, `test` has been declared inside of `jQuery(document).ready(function($)` and as such should be globally available to functions inside of `jQuery(document).ready(function($)`. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: @pmandell why should it work?

Comment: I can't see why `test` would be undefined. Are you able to reproduce the problem in a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: @billyonecan I haven't tested this with fiddle. However, this problem is not just with a single plugin. All plugins that I have loaded on the page, exhibit the same problem.

Comment: Are both of the above code blocks in the same `$(document).ready(function()`? That's the only thing I think would be the cause of the problem based on what you've said

Comment: @billyonecan Both are within the same `$(document).ready(function()`.